# C# Scalable solution to using Json.Net to filter out properties based upon user interaction

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, scalability

I am using C# Newtonsoft.net to serialize data into Json. In my program, I will be getting users to interact with parts of my data, and I only want the serialized data to be the data they interact with.

Code below shows an example of creating a class A, and interactive with to properties.

```
[DataContract]
public class B
{
  [DataMember]
  public int Property1 { get; set; } = 0;

  [DataMember]
  public int Property2 { get; set; } = 0;
}

[DataContract]
public class A
{
  [DataMember]
  public int Property1 { get; set; } = 0;

  [DataMember]
  public int Property2 { get; set; } = 0;

  [DataMember]
  public B B { get; set; } = new B();
}

public class JsonTester
{
  public void Test()
  {
    var a = new A();
    a.Property1 = 1;
    a.B.Property1 = 1;

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
      ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver()
    });
  }
}
```

My expected json output would be the following:

```
{
  "Property1": 1,
  "B": {
    "Property1": 1
  }
}
```

As you notice, Property2 is not in the json, because I only set a.Property1 / a.B.Property1.

If my code did not have a.B.Property1 = 1, I would expect the json to look like this:

```
{
  "Property1": 1
}
```

Now, the question is about doing this in the most scalable way. Clearly creating a separate bool for every single property is not a scalable solution.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

Comment: That's ignoring permanently

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using `[DataContract]`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could deal with this.

You could use nullable types, and the [`NullValueHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) enumeration

> Include null values when serializing and deserializing objects.

Or you could use `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`

> Ignore members where the member value is the same as the member's
> default value when serializing objects so that it is not written to
> JSON. This option will ignore all default values (e.g. null for
> objects and nullable types; 0 for integers, decimals and floating
> point numbers; and false for booleans). The default value ignored can
> be changed by placing the DefaultValueAttribute on the property.

**Example**

```
public class B
{
   [DefaultValue(1)]
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
   public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
   [DefaultValue(1)]
   public int Property1 { get; set; } 

   public int Property2 { get; set; } 

   public B B { get; set; } = new B();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var a = new A();
a.Property1 = 1;
a.B.Property1 = 2;

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
   DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
   NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "B": {
    "Property1": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I was very clear on the question. -- It's not about handling default values, but when interaction with user occurs.

Comment: I will be loading data to some state..... then after that the user will touch properties